# How can I adjust scaling of W10 to match as closely as possible to W7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, high-dpi

On Win7 I use scaling of 125% and that was enough to cover all my needs. However, on Win10, I had to up it to 135% to even barely match the scale factor. But the issue is that since it works differently it is partially broken for me. There are a few glaring issues at hand:

1. Blurry text in old windows elements like MMC.
2. Unscaled text in some cases, for example dialogue windows, like, when you import some .reg file and a warning pops-up - the text is INCREDIBLY small for 135% scale, but the window itself is scaled an there is plenty of space of bigger font size.

I could fix the blur of 1) by setting HDPIAWARE flag for specific applications, that's fine. But the problem is that it still wont be scaled at all and is really hard to read.

I could not find any way fix the 2). I tried using solutions that enable old Win8.1 scaling (like http://windows10-dpi-fix.xpexplorer.com) but still to no avail.

Is there some other aspects of scaling I'm missing that can help me bring it closer to Windows XP/7 style? My eyesight is incredibly poor.

EDIT: To clarify, I have no issues choosing custom scaling, I can make it 200% if needed, I know how this option works and where to set it. problem is, this will make elements bigger but barely affects the text. Notice dialogue window label text is unchanged:
https://www.screenshotcomparison.com/comparison/9475

This applies to 70% of the screen text, atually.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Text size adjustments work perfectly for me, and I do not know why not for you.